# Hot to preserve $http response on page refresh in AngularJs?

Tags: ajax, angularjs, session, request, page-refresh

The idea is simple. There's a Login $http POST request to the server, the user is authenticated and the server returns information about the user. I put that information in a Service and I can use it across different Controllers easily, but when I refresh the page, the data is lost... and I have to log in again in order to receive the data from the server. Is there any way to keep the server's response even if the page is refreshed?

This is the Service doing the $http request:

```
app.factory('AuthService', function ($http) {

    var authService = {};

    authService.login = function (credentials) {

        var req = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'api/v1/login',
            data: { email: credentials.email, password: credentials.password }
        };

        return $http(req);
    };

    return authService;

});
```

This is the Controller using the Service:

```
app.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $http, AuthService, SessionService) {
    $scope.credentials = {
        email: '',
        password: '',
        remember: true
    };

    $scope.login = function (credentials) {

        var authentication = AuthService.login(credentials);
        authentication.success(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            if (response.status.code="ok"){
                SessionService.set('auth', true);
            } else {
                alert("Couldn't perform Login!");
            }
        }).error(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: Have you looked into ngStorage? http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngStorage

Comment: what platform are you using serverside?

Comment: I'm using Laravel on the server side @MichaelColeman

Comment: I'm trying not to use too many modules, but I'll look into ngStoarge too. So far I kinda managed to come up with a solution by using window.localStorage @MatthewGreen

Comment: excellent, angular works beautifully with laravel for authentication. It's hard to put into a single answer as there is a bit to it. And I suspect you might be better off if you go about it differently, basically I think @Nicholas Smith's answer is the right way, but Laravel has its own authentication mechanism for this and I **highly recommend** you use it. so 2 questions: 1. is there a specific reason why you are not using cookies? 2. please provide as much info as possible about what you have setup so far. escpecially the PHP for the `api/v1/login` route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the authentication response in a session cookie with $cookieStore (will live until you explicitly invalidate it in your logout mechanism or user closes the browser window).  You'd need to re-read that cookie when your app initializes to pull the info back in, and only direct the user to your login form if the cookie doesn't exist.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookieStore

Comment: Thanks for your response. While searching the web I stumbled upon Local Storage? Isn't that a better solution than $cookieStore? And why (not)?

Comment: Local storage could work, but information stored is not automatically sent along with a request, so I think you'd have to have your page load, then run some javascript to extract the info from local storage, and then send them to the server through an API call to handle your login, vs just having it available with the initial page request.